# high CPU usage on pantheon-mail idle

Tags: release-hera, pantheon-mail

I'm experiencing an unusual CPU usage on pantheon-mail idle - (40% - 50% of CPU or higher). However, when the process is killed, everything goes smoothly (as usual). This high CPU usage reduces significantly my laptop's battery life (instead of having screen 7-8 hours I'm getting about 3-4h). Any ideas about how to get rid of it without constantly killing the process? (once killed, no notifications pop up...etc, so I'd like to keep the default settings...).

Answer (score 0):

Switch to Mozilla Thunderbird. Really. Trust me. You can even remove pantheon mail based on Geary Mail from Ubuntu.